# Insert 1000 rows in php each time different

Tags: php, mysql, insert

We have this code:

```
for($i=1;$i=1000;$i++){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO testing VALUES ('".$i."')");
  //do some other testing
}
```

It enters the same value 1000 times but what I need is that every time (from this 1000 times) to insert a different value.

For example:

```
$n = rand(1,300);
$n2 = $n/2;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO testing VALUES ('".$i."')");
```

So do this action for 1000 times and each time to do it again. Not to insert the same data from first result it is possible?

Comment: for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original loop is *nearly* correct, with the exception of the 2nd statement. It should be a comparison, instead you are setting.

Correct version `for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++){`. Notice the `$i <= 1000;` instead of `$i = 1000;`.